# How to spin up a Heroku app with a Python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, heroku, simplehttpserver

I have a simple Flask app running to listen for the Heroku PORT

```
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    port = int(environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

I want to serve a simple Python Server too which is in a different file called sim_serv.py. How can i do this?

Comment: You want to host two server in same heroku app?

Comment: It might help if we could see part or all of sim_serv.py

Comment: Looks like others have achieved this, albeit a bit hacky: https://medium.com/@nadayar/heroku-fu-multiple-servers-on-one-dyno-6fc68d57b373